# prove that metric and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Denote $E$ the set of all real sequences $\{a_n\}$ such that $|a_n| \leq 1$ for every positive integers $n$.Let $\{a_n\},\{b_n\} \in E$

Prove that $$d(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{|a_n-b_n|}{2^n}$$
 deﬁnes a metric on E.

Comment: Do you know the definition of metric？I think it a very basic and direct verification

Comment: You can use $\LaTeX$ here putting your math between $'s. It makes it a lot more readable.

Comment: @ulilaka  could you give any link for latex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d$ will be a metric if it is a finite non-negative, non-degenerate symmetric function from $E \times E$ to $\mathbf{R}$ verifying the triangle inequality. It's clear from the definition that $d(\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}) = d(\{b_n\}, \{a_n\})$, since sum is commutative. Also, it's non-negative because it's the sum of non-negative factors (due to the absolute value). Let's check that it's finite: remember that the geometric $\sum q^{n}$ converges for $| q |  < 1$. Now, if $|a_{n}| \leq 1 \forall n \in \mathbf{N}$, we have:
$$
|a_{n} - b_{n}| \leq |a_{n}| + |b_{n}| \leq 2
$$
where I used the triangle inequality. Diving each term like the above by $2^{n}$ and summing up we get:
$$
d(\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_{n} - b_{n}|}{2^{n}} \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}
$$
Because of the considerations about geometric series I made, the sum in the right hand side is convergent and dominates $d(\{a_n\}, \{b_n\})$, so it must converge as well. The only way such distance to be zero is if each summand is zero, since they're all non-negative, which in turn implies $a_{n} = b_{n}$ for every $n$. Finally, triangle inequality follows from $|a_n - b_n| \leq |a_n - c_n| + |c_n - b_n|$, dividing by $2^{n}$ and summing up as I did above. I suggest working through the details, because it's a routine verification.

Comment: please do not post any answer (you can comment below the question)unless the OP has showed what he/she has tried to solve it... Please do not encourage this kind of questions (I have done same thing as you did  sometime ago and got the same comment which i have commented for you)